# Get back documents from MongoDB stored in UTC format

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have documents that have dates stored in MongoDB in the UTC format: `2016-01-28T01:00:00Z` where Z represents the UTC time.

What I am trying to do is find all documents, for which the date has not expired (date_stored_in_DB > Today's Date). However I am confused about the right way of doing this.

**Approach 1:** Should I convert today's date into the Z-format (as shown above) first and start looking into the database? That way it would just be matching strings.

**Approach 2:** Should I get all records from the database and convert each date into the parsable date format like 02/03/2016 and compare with today's date? I am thinking regex here but I am not sure

**Approach 3**: Your suggestions?

I am using reactivemongo with scala & play framework to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to convert today's date to UTC:

```
 val utcString = new DateTime(now).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

You can pass this value to a `$gt` MongoDB query to retrieve the non-expired records.

Answer (score 3):

If you stored your date as an ISODate type then you can just query against it like so:

db.yourcollection.find({"date" : { $gte : new ISODate("2016-01-28T01:00:00Z") }});

The $gte operator queries for greater than or equal to. See [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/)  for additional informaton.

Querying all the records to then filter them out is typically not a good idea.